# Getting ERROR 1064 (42000): while restoring MySQL database

Tags: mysql

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*/' at line 1

Taken database dump by below query.

mysqldump -h 172.16.0.119 -u root -p --routines --events --complete-insert database >  /home/backup/database.sql

Comment: Add your mysql query.

Comment: There seems a problem with comments in your query. Please share your SQL.

Comment: provide us the query

Comment: Taken database dump by below query.

mysqldump -h 172.16.0.119 -u root -p --routines --events --complete-insert database > /home/backup/database.sql

Comment: @VinayS MySQL server version is same for both query dump and restore?

Comment: Yes @MiyaG Both are of same version

Comment: @VinayS 
Okay what query are you using to restore data.?

Comment: @MiyaG I tried
1. mysql -u root -p database < database.sql
2. source /home/backup/database.sql

Comment: Have you tried same as dump. mysql -u root -p --routines --events --complete-insert database < /home/backup/database.sql